# How can I search Gmail for password-protected PDFs?

Tags: gmail, passwords, pdf, gmail-attachments

I'm looking for an attachment that happens to be a password-protected PDF file (you need to type the password to open it). Is there a way to search Gmail for such files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for PDF attachments, certainly. But Gmail has no idea whether a PDF is password-protected or not.

Searching for

```
filename:pdf has:attachment
```

should return all of your conversations with a PDF attachment.

If the sender mentioned that it was password-protected in the body of the message, this might be helpful:

```
filename:pdf has:attachment password
```

Comment: @Vaddadi: Good point. I've adjusted my answer (and will adjust my filter).